# Augment a Type declaration from a library

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have imported a library `mycoollib` which resides in `node_modules` and has the following folder and file structure

```
node_modules
   - mycoollib
      - src
          mycoollogic.js
      - types
          index.d.ts
```

The `index.d.ts`, which contains the type definitions of `mycoollib`, is this

```
/// <reference types="node" />

export type MyCoolType = {
  func1: () => void
  func2: () => void
}
```

In my application I need to augment `MyCoolType` type definition, adding for instance a third function. So I create `my-cool-type-augmentation.d.ts` file in my `src` folder like this

```
declare namespace mycoollib {
    export type MyCoolType = {
      augmentedFunction: () => void
    }
}
```

but this solution seems not to work, since the compiler signals an issue when I try to use `augmentedFunction` on objects of type `MyCoolType`.

I have tried also using the module declaration, like this

```
declare module "mycoollib" {
    export type MyCoolType = {
      augmentedFunction: () => void
    }
}
```

but in this case the compiler signals the fact that there is a ***Duplicate identifier 'MyCoolType'*** error in `index.d.ts` and in `my-cool-type-augmentation.d.ts`. This solution works for me in other cases where I have to augment **interfaces**, but does not seem to work with **types**.

Comment: I believe this is strictly a feature that works for interfaces, not types as you suspected.

Comment: @Evert is correct. `type` declarations cannot be augmented. If you own `mycoollib` make `MyCoolType` an `interface` to enable augmentation. If you do not, file an issue with the proprietor. This behavior is intentional.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad. Thanks for the clarification, Just one additional question: why is it intentional? I mean: which is the reason why you can with Interfaces but not with Type aliases?

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because it is not supposed to work according to documentation:

> ... the key distinction is that a type cannot be re-opened to add new properties vs an interface which is always extendable.

[Differences Between Type Aliases and Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces)